# Date format + postgresql + node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, date

I have issue in date comparison in node.js with postgresql DB. consider i have to following row in my table...

```
id |        xxxxx         | totalrecords | insertedrecords |     latesttime      |  status  
----+-------------------------+--------------+-----------------+---------------------+----------
  1 | 2017-07-27 12:30:00.063 |            3 |              50 | 2017-05-25 18:46:30 | success
```

In the above table i'm retrieving the latest time to do some comparison using node.js

When i query and retrieve this latesttime it's showing as below:

```
2017-05-25T13:16:30.000Z  --> NOTE -5:30 is added may be GMT (Why its added???)
```

SO in my date comparison i have to following dates

```
2017-05-25T18:47:56
2017-05-25T18:48:48
```

My date comparison logic is as follows:

```
var output = json.data.filter(function(x){console.log(x.time); return x.time > res.rows[0].latesttime});
```

My output is always an empty array [].

Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance......

Comment: 1) 'Z' at the end of the datetime means 'UTC'.
2) Why filter on nodejs side? You can compare this in SQL (this will be faster): 
i.e: select * from table where xxx > latesttime

Comment: @Dmitry Chirkin Actually this date 2017-05-25T18:47:56
2017-05-25T18:48:48 is not from sql table, this is from external API, So i have filter the data greater than this latesttime..

Comment: @Dmitry Chirkin Also Why `2017-05-25 18:46:30` is converted to `2017-05-25T13:16:30.000Z` its 5:30 hrs back

Comment: Maybe you still can filter on the sql side.

Comment: Regarding your question about 'convertion'. 
Actually it's not converted, it's just displayed in 'UTC' format (because of this 'z' symbol at the end)